# What are the best manual settings for shooting a full solar eclipse?

Tags: sun, eclipse

The last time I shot a partial eclipse with my Canon T3i camera, and was maxed out at 1/4000 and between 2.8-4 aperture, do I need to go this extreme for a full eclipse?

Any other tips for former solar eclipse photographers?

Comment: You need to give us a lens.

Comment: The best settings are the ones that give the result you want.

Comment: Do you have a solar filter?

Answer (score 4):

There are plenty of very well written online resources that discuss how to capture a solar eclipse.

Pretty much none of them say, "Here are the settings you need to use." There are just way too many variables that will affect what works best by too great an amount to be able to say any particular exposure value is optimal. Some of these variable include:

- The angle of the sun in the sky, which can vary all the way from near the horizon to the zenith based upon your viewing location. The sun and moon are much brighter when directly overhead than when near the horizon. This is due to the angle at which their light passes through the Earth's atmosphere.
- The density of the air between you and the sun. In addition to the sun's angle in the sky, this can also vary with the altitude of your viewing location and the amount of water vapor and other particulates in the air.
- Cloud cover. You can still shoot most of an eclipse through light clouds, but exposure must be adjusted based on the exact density of the the clouds at any given time. You probably won't be able to get much of anything during totality through even a very light cloud layer, though.
- During totality: viewing location and the amount of cloud cover in areas that reflect the sun's light back towards the moon as well as the percentage of land vs. sea and the typographical features of the areas near the moon's shadow over a very large area of the side of the Earth facing the moon and sun will have an effect on the brightness of the "Earthshine" reflected by the moon as it blocks the sun from view. The more reflective the parts of the Earth facing the moon are, the brighter the moon will be.

Totality will be much darker than any other portion of the eclipse. It will be very much like shooting during a night with very little or no moon in the sky. Even for any particular viewing location and viewing conditions, your exposure will need to vary significantly depending on exactly what aspects you wish to emphasize. The Sun's corona using a very narrow angle of view?Details on the Moon's surface reflecting "earthshine?" Or the surrounding landscape using a very wide angle of view?